# Error on mean sigma differ if fit without normalization or with it. Why?

Tags: root-framework

When I fitted a histogram using Gaussian its error on mean and sigma seems to be fine. You can look at it here [image: Gaussian fit after normalization].

But, when I first normalized the histogram and fitted it with Gaussian its parameters value is exactly same as previous case but the error on mean and sigma is almost equal to the actual value or greater. [image: Gaussian fit without normalization]

One of the reason for this is that it may be happening because it is taking error as 1/sqrt{n} and after normalizing n decreased and hence error increased.

Please let me know what is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to call

```
hist->Sumw2()
```

before rescaling the histogram. Otherwise the uncertainties on all bin contents are just the square roots of the bin contents (which is a huge relative error for bin contents smaller than 1, which is the case when after rescaling). `SumW2` triggers to store the sum of all weights squared and not only the bin contents (i.e. the sum of weights in each bin).

See also [the documentation of `Sumw2()`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTH1.html#aefa4ee94f053ec3d217f3223b01fa014) for further details (and also the explanation of weights on the top of the TH1 documentation page).